# Swift Weird UIAccessibility Crash

Tags: swift, crash, crashlytics

I have taken over a code from someone else and the source code is written in Swift. I have made my changes but when I added the Crashlytics for crash reporting, I keep on seeing UIAccessibility crashes. Mainly 2 crashes keep repeating,

```
UIAccessibility _copyAttributeValueCallback
```

and

```
UIAccessibility _copyMultipleAttributeValuesCallback
```

I have searched every last thread of stack over flow with the keywords Swift and UIAccessbility but still cannot make out why it's occurring. Any idea what I am missing here?

Edit: This is the crash report from Crashlyitcs.
[image]

Comment: I'm not confident with UIAccessibility, but I think that you could help yourself if you post the related code and informations on when it's crashing

Comment: @FredericP I have edited the question to include the crash report, no idea how to get the code from here.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Kris As skymatt70 has said that it has something to do with the Crashlytics SDK. I have not uploaded the new app yet but I will upload a new version next month and then see if it happens. That is the only reason I have not accepted his answer yet.

Comment: hey @FarrukhJaveid, i have same issue in my objective c project. Did you upload your version, any news about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this same issue and have concluded it's not a crash and an issue with Crashlytics.  It was pointing to the AppDelegate class definition, no actual code.  I recently uploaded a copy of my app to test with TestFlight as a release version only giving myself access.  I launched it a few times had no issues using the app but went back to my debug version.  The next time I checked Crashlytics, my error free to me testing showed 7 of these crashes on an iPad Mini 2 while I was testing on an iPhone 6S.  No one else had access to this particular build.

Also, a new release to some testing customers showed this error on my latest release for a customer who hadn't yet downloaded it.  Strange things are certainly afoot at the Circle K for this particular crash.

In addition, Apple shows none of these crashes!  As I type this I'm realizing these crashes only show up on builds distributed via TestFlight.  We use Crashlytics for internal testing and TestFlight to test with clients prior to release.  Does this match your experience?

Comment: I overtook the app from someone and I had to do major overhaul of the app in terms or architecture so I used Crashlytics as the means of error reporting. It's on the production as well. I would have tried Xcode's error reporting but I don't trust it one bit. However, that said, it's definitely a crash since it's been occurring to my clients as well as my testers.